# How to use jQuery selectors with variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen lots of similar questions, but none of answers worked in my case.

A variable is set depending on a document width:

```
if ($(document).width() < 1400) {
    var tblProdukty = document.getElementById('tblProdukty1280');
}
else {
    var tblProdukty = document.getElementById('tblProdukty1920');
}
```

Then I would like to do something like this: $("#tblProdukty1280 > tbody").empty(); but with a variable set as above into something like this:

```
$("#" + tblProdukty + " > tbody").empty();
```

or

```
$(`${tblProdukty}` + " > tbody").empty();
```

I have tried different combinations of concatenation and injection and could not figure it out. I got the following error message:
*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableElement] > tbody*

Can you please advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 different ways:

first, you can use the `tblProdukty` variable as reference to the element:

```
if ($(document).width() < 1400) {
    var tblProdukty = $("#tblProdukty1280");
}
else {
    var tblProdukty = $("#tblProdukty1920"); 
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
tblProdukty.find("tbody").empty();
```

OR you can do something like that:

```
if ($(document).width() < 1400) {
    var tblProdukty = "tblProdukty1280";
}
else {
    var tblProdukty = "tblProdukty1920";
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
$(`#${tblProdukty}` + " > tbody").empty();
```

Comment: Indeed it works. I tried the first way... Many Thanks!